# Kubernetes UI is not working

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster set up. I tried to install UI from [this URL](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ui/) but when I try to access the UI from my browser I get following Error:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "endpoints \"kube-ui\" not found",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {
    "name": "kube-ui",
    "kind": "endpoints"
  },
  "code": 404
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run: `kubectl proxy`

And you must going to http://127.0.0.1:8001/ui/

It's better?